# Check if unbound text box is equal to a string

Tags: ms-access, vba

In an access form, I have an unbound text box when contains a formula. The formula returns "Yes" or "No" based on whether the form has been completed (it ensure that all required boxes are filled in).

On the same form, I have a command button which I want to use to filter out completed forms. Basically, it is a button that save "Save Record" and when clicked, the form - if completed - should disappear (i.e. be filtered out).

Below is what I put in, but I don't know VBA.

```
Private Sub bttn_Save_Click()
    Me.Filter = Me.MainFormComplete = Yes
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

How do I get check to see if my field (MainFormComplete) is equal to "Yes"?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are trying to do, but it could be:

```
Private Sub bttn_Save_Click()
    Me.Filter = "MainFormComplete = 'Yes'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

or:

```
Private Sub bttn_Save_Click()
    Me.Filter = "MainFormComplete <> 'Yes'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
if Me.MainFormComplete = Yes then
    ....
end if
```

the textbox might not be readable if text was simply entered and not saved. read the text:

```
if Me.MainFormComplete.Text = Yes then 'or "Yes" or True
    ....
end if
```